# Problem with url after building an angular app

Tags: angular, build

I have trouble to fix an Url problem. When I run the application on localhost it works fine but when I build it and run it on a test server then the app tries to communicate with localhost.

I have a code to switch the url depending on if it runs on local or on a test server.

Here's my code:

```
baseUrl: string = this.isLocal ? 'http://localhost:8080/anypage' : '/anypage';

 isLocal() {
    return (window.location.host.indexOf("localhost") > -1)
  }
```

It should work but it's not working. Am I missing something or is there an easier way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call your function:

```
  baseUrl: string = this.isLocal() ? 'http://localhost:8080/anypage' : '/anypage';

  isLocal() {
    return (window.location.host.indexOf("localhost") > -1)
  }
```

I'm afraid to sound boring, but if you need to detect `prod` or `dev` environment than more «Angular way» is [this](https://angular.io/guide/build).